# Completely remove openstack from system after installation from devstack script

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am installing OpenStack on my local machine via [this](http://devstack.org/guides/single-machine.html) link. But I am having trouble in completely removing installed components from my local machine. I ran following command:-

```
$ sudo ./unstack.sh
tgtadm: can't send the request to the tgt daemon, Transport endpoint is not connected
tgtd seems to be in a bad state, restarting...
stop: Unknown instance: 
tgt start/running, process 14629
tgt stop/waiting
Volume group "stack-volumes" not found
Skipping volume group stack-volumes
```

And file are still present in /opt/stack and /usr/local/bin/. But manually removing these file will not be a good option.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The **unstack.sh** script only stops the services without removing them.
Devstack's folder contains a **clean.sh** script that removes openstack and dependencies so you can run something like this:

```
cd path/to/devstack

# There's no need to call unstack.sh explicitly
# clean.sh invokes that script itself.
./clean.sh
```

Answer (score 7):

Follow the following 3 steps:

1. `./clean.sh`
2. `rm -rf /opt/stack`
3. `rm -rf /usr/local/bin` (careful, this will remove everything installed to your local bin folder, which might include previously installed applications).

For more info of all the impacted files and directories [this link](https://www.berrange.com/posts/2012/11/20/what-devstack-does-to-your-host-when-setting-up-openstack-on-fedora-17/).

Comment: Careful, there might be other things in /usr/local/bin prior to devstack.

Comment: **Highly recommend** using `rm -f /usr/local/bin/openstack*` in place of step 3 as listed in this post. This command will forcefully remove the scripts `openstack` and `openstack-inventory` and any others that begin with "openstack" from your `/usr/local/bin/` folder.

Answer (score 3):

unstack doesn't clean out /opt/stack.  or purge all dependency packages.  or clean all eggs out of python.

I recommend running devstack in a VM.  It's easy enough to simply remove the VM and rebuild from scratch.

Example shell script for creating a devstack VM for kvm:

```
#!/bin/sh

/usr/bin/vmbuilder kvm ubuntu -v --suite=oneiric --libvirt=qemu:///system --flavour=server --arch=amd64 --cpus=2 --mem=4096 --swapsize=2048 --rootsize=30480 --ip=192.168.122.236 --hostname=devstack --user=stack --name=stack --pass=stack --addpkg=git --addpkg=screen --addpkg=vim --addpkg=strace --addpkg=lsof --addpkg=nmap --addpkg=subversion --addpkg=acpid --addpkg=tcpdump --addpkg=python-pip --addpkg=wget --addpkg=htop --mirror=http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu --components='main,universe' --addpkg=openssh-server --dns=8.8.8.8 --dest=/virts/devstack
```

Comment: clean.sh may give you better mileage, unstack.sh does not for all reasons I raised.